# Woocommerce - Latest modified date

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Previously I have added [Show created and modified product date on WooCommerce pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66010822/11987538) answer code to make my single product page shows the latest modified date.

However, I have to rebuild the single product page with Elementor pro (Theme builder) for some reason. The code is not working anymore on the single product page. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with Elementor and the standard WooCommerce hooks can be a hassle because some hooks don't exist or need to be placed in the single product template.
You have 2 alternative options:

1. Make sure that this hook is there by placing the correct product widget in your template which contains this hook.
2. Modify your code: Create a shortcode instead of a hook and place the shortcode where you want in your template:

   `add_shortcode( 'my_custom_product_date', 'woocommerce_product_date' );`

Put `[my_custom_product_date]`in your Elementor template.